# Formally, why is it meaningful to multiply, but not add, different units?

Tags: unit-of-measure

I know a bit of dimensional analysis from physics.

Simple example, if you have

$10J\cdot m^{-1} \times x = 20J\cdot kg\cdot m^{-2}$

then you can deduce that $x=2kg\cdot m^{-1}$, the units being determined in the obvious, natural way.

You cannot add Newtons units to metre units, but you can multiply them to get a new unit of Newton-metres.

This is *intuitively* meaningful to me and requires no further explanation. But in the formal, axiom-and-theorem sense, what allows me to multiply arbitrary units, and what forbids me from adding different units?

Comment: Structurally, the allowed operations on units form an abelian group under multiplication, and all other operations are forbidden. I don't have a deep or intuitive understanding of why it should be defined this way, despite wondering about this for a long time. Everyone I've talked to about this just remembers the rule, and assumes there is a good reason without really understanding what it is.

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely an interesting thought. Nothing forbid you in any sense. Mathematics is an abstract art where you can do pretty much anything your want. The only reason you don't see units being added is because the interpretation of the result is not meaningful in any immediate way. But there is no axiomatic rule saying you can multiply units but not add them.

A similar question students often ask if why when we multiply matrices, we do that weird way instead of just multiplying them component wise? The same answer holds; we don't do it because the result isn't meaningful as far as elementary mathematics goes. However in some cases it is (see [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))). In that sense, if you can find a way to derive some meaning from adding units, then perhaps it would be useful to add different units.

There is actually an inherent difference between mathematics and how we choose to ***interpret*** that mathematics. In the field of pure maths, the concept of units is in some sense non existent; saying $5$ newtons is an ***interpretation*** of the abstract number $5$ into a meaningful real world thing, namely, the magnitude of a force.

If you wanted you are free to say, I am now going to define the addition of units. Consider a $5N$ force and an area of $10 \ m^2$. I will define the unit sum (denoted $\oplus$) as:

$$
5\ N \oplus 10 \ m^2 = 15 \ N\oplus m^2
$$

where the units of the answer is $N\oplus m^2$. See what you can discover about such a system and whether you can derive any meaning from it. Do share your findings!